# c++ How to generate random number between 1 and 10^6?

Tags: c++, random

I realize that the maximum number `rand()` can generate is 32767. Is there anyway I can generate random numbers with value between 1 and 10^6(1 million) without external libraries?

Comment: If you can use C++11, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Do You use (ancient) 16 bit platform?

Comment: 1) generate a number that is either 1 or 2.  2) if it is 1 generate a number between 1 and 10, if it is 2 generate a number between 1 and 10 and add 10.3) generalize for larger numbers

Comment: @JacekCz, for example any MSVC

Comment: @RiaD Im surpised, but yes.C stdlih.h rand() has poor opinion, use modern (like in answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "external libraries" but it's quite easy with the C++11 `random` library.

```
std::default_random_engine engine{std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> range{1, 1'000'000};

int randomly_generated_number = range(engine);
int another_randomly_generated_number = range(engine);
```

For general purpose random numbers, I'd probably recommend using `std::mt19937` (or `std::mt19937_64` on 64-bit machines) instead of `std::default_random_engine` but the default engine is better for learning purposes.

Comment: Writing numbers like `1'000'000` is allowed?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Not sure when it became a thing (I think C++14?) but the apostrophe symbol is allowed to be used as a separator in numbers.

Comment: Yes, this came about in C++14. "Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator. They are ignored by the compiler. (since C++14)" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: @FredLarson Thanks for clearing that up, also thanks Xirema